# Pushing object onto array which is inside an object (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array inside an object `addedCertificates` and I want to push values into it.

```
   const addShift = () => {        
    setShiftList((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        id: shiftList.length,
        date: '',
        startTime: '',
        endTime: '',
        addedCertificates: [],
        selectedCertificate: '',            
      },
    ]);               
};
```

When a button click occurs I want to push the `selectedCertificate` into the `addedCertificates` array. The function will look something like this:

```
 const addCertificate = (index) => {        
    const list = [...shiftList];        
    list[index]['addedCertificates'] = list[index]['selectedCertificate'];
    setShiftList(list);
    console.log('shiftList from add certificate', shiftList)
}
```

Right now the addedCertificates just get replaced with the selectedCertificate, but I want to keep the already added certificates.
I cant seem to use `.push` on the array like this:

```
list[index]['addedCertificates'].push(list[index]['selectedCertificate']);
```

Does any one know how I can push values to this array?

Comment: Don’t mutate state - https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state even if it looks like you’re not mutating, you’re still mutating the object that’s in the array which can lead to odd unintuitive behaviours later. Never mutate state

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the push function in your case.
Because you have created a new list by const `list = [...shiftList];`
So React knows the list has been updated and will re-render the page.

In other cases, you can try as follows

```
list[index]['addedCertificates'] = [...list[index]['addedCertificates'], list[index]['selectedCertificate']];
```

Hope it can be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 const addCertificateToShiftList = (index, objectToPush) => {

    setShiftList(prev => {
     const updatedShiftList = [...prev];
     const updatedShift = { ...updatedShiftList[index] };
     updatedShift.addedCertificates.push(objectToPush);
     updatedShiftList[index] = updatedShift;
     return updatedShiftList;
   });
 };
```